# How to use a "double layered" decorator without using the @ syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapper

Say I have this decorator:

```
def decorator_with_args(decorator_arg1, decorator_arg2):                
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if decorator_arg1 == 'arg1' and decorator_arg2 == 'arg2':
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Typically you decorate a function like this:

```
@decorator_with_args('arg1', 'arg2')
def function():
    return 'foo'

>>> foo = function()
'foo'
```

How do I call it without using the `@` syntax?.

I know that way you call it if it's only a single layered decorator (i.e. decorator without args) is that you literally wrap it in the decorator function like this:

```
>>> foo = decorator(function)
'foo'
```

Note the `function` isn't called. How will this work if both the decorator and the function have arguments that need to be passed?

```
>>> foo = decorator_with_args(decorator(wrapped_function))
```

But then where do the `*args` and `**kwargs` of the decorator and the original function go?

Comment: That makes no sense. `decorator` doesn't exist outside of `decorator_with_args`.

Comment: `foo = decorator_with_args('arg1', 'arg2)(function)()`

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry, I meant hypothetically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decorator_with_args()` is a decorator factory – that is, a function which returns a decorator. That means that in order to use it without the `@` syntax, you need to call it with its arguments, and then call the result with your function as an argument.

Here's how that looks:

```
def function():
    return 'foo'

function = decorator_with_args('arg1', 'arg2')(function)
```

```
>>> function()
'foo'
```

Notice that this is analogous to the difference between using a regular decorator with or without the `@` syntax:

```
@deco
def func(arg):
    # ...
```

is to

```
def func(arg):
    # ...

func = deco(func)
```

as

```
@deco_fac(x, y)
def func(arg):
    # ...
```

is to

```
def func(arg):
    # ...

func = deco_fac(x, y)(func)
```